# How can I display html using a view that displays multiple object items and after one of those items has been deleted from the Django database?

Tags: html, django, view, model, rendering

I have the following models:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Hotel', 'Hotel'),
    ('Restaurant', 'Restaurant'),
    ('Attraction', 'Attraction'),
    ('Activity', 'Activity')
)

LABEL_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'primary'),
    ('S', 'secondary'),
    ('D', 'danger')
)

class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/")    
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.name}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    
    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.name}"


class Order1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    step = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=0)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step_duration = models.FloatField(default=0)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def get_total_duration(self):
        Pass
    
    def get_total_price(self):
        return F"£{self.step_duration * 20}"


class Order2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    step = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=0)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step_duration = models.FloatField(default=0)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def get_total_duration(self):
        Pass
    
    def get_total_price(self):
        return F"£{self.step_duration * 20}"
```

I have the following views:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def OrderSummaryView(request):
        try:            
            order1 = Order1.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
            order2 = Order2.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {'object1': order1, 'object2': order2}
            
            
            return render(request, "order_summary.html", context)
            
            
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")

@login_required
def add_to_cart1(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
        )
    order_qs = Order1.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1            
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
        else:            
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
            return redirect("product", slug=slug)
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order1.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date, step=1)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
    return redirect("product", slug=slug)

@login_required
def add_to_cart2(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
        )
    order_qs = Order2.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1            
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
        else:            
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
            return redirect("product", slug=slug)
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order2.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
    return redirect("product", slug=slug)


@login_required
def remove_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order1.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, 
        ordered=False
        )

    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            # order.items.remove(order_item)                           
            #  order.delete()
            order_item.delete()
            order_qs.delete()

            messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your cart.")
            return redirect("product", slug=slug)
            
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your your cart.")
            return redirect("product", slug=slug)
            
    else:        
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order.")
        return redirect("product", slug=slug)
        

@login_required
def remove_from_cart2(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order2.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, 
        ordered=False
        )

    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            # order.items.remove(order_item)         
            # order.delete()
            order_item.delete()
            order_qs.delete()
            messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your cart.")
            return redirect("product", slug=slug)
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your your cart.")
            return redirect("product", slug=slug)
    else:        
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order.")
        return redirect("product", slug=slug)
```

I have the following order_summary.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<!--Main layout-->
<main class="mt-5 pt-4">
    <div style="max-width: 70%; position: relative; margin: auto;">
        <!-- <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap"> -->
            <h2>Booking Summary</h2>
            <table class="tabled">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th> 
                        <th scope="col">Address</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>                                             
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for order_item in object1.items.all %}
                    
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th> -->
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>{{ order_item.item.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order_item.item.address }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order_item.item.category }}</td>
                        <td><a class='btn btn-warning btn-md my-0 p float-right' href="{% url 'item-list' %}">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'remove-from-cart' order_item.item.slug %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-md my-0 p" >Remove from cart
                        </a></td>
                                             
                    </tr>
                    {% empty %}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">Your cart is empty</td>                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <a class='btn btn-primary float-right' href="{% url 'index' %}">Continue shopping</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>

            <table class="tabled">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col"></th> 
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for order_item in object2.items.all %}
                    
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>{{ order_item.item.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order_item.item.address }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order_item.item.category }}</td>
                        <td><a class='btn btn-warning btn-md my-0 p float-right' href="{% url 'item-list2' %}">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'remove-from-cart2' order_item.item.slug %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-md my-0 p" >Remove from cart
                        </a></td>
                                             
                    </tr>
                    {% empty %}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">Your cart is empty</td>                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <a class='btn btn-primary float-right' href="{% url 'index' %}">Continue shopping</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>        



                    {% if object.get_total %}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><b>Vehicle Size</b></td>
                        <td><b></b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><b>Duration</b></td>
                        <td><b></b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><b>Total Price</b></td>
                        <td><b></b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <a class='btn btn-warning float-right ml-2' href="{% url 'checkout' %}">Proceed to checkout</a>
                            <a class='btn btn-primary float-right' href="{% url 'index' %}">Continue shopping</a>                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                </tbody>
            </table>        
        <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
    
    
    
</main>
<!--Main layout-->  
    
{% endblock %}
```

The application defaults back to the landing html (should be order_summary.html) after an item has been deleted from either Order1 or Order2 and the Cart that displays the order has been clicked. I would like to be able to display the order summary that displays both items, delete one of the items, and then have the user directed to the order summary (the Cart) but only able to see the remaining item. I think the issue is in the view. can anyone help? There are other views that add and delete the items from Order1 and Order2. The bottom part of the html from {% if object.get_total %} is not finished.

Comment: I don’t see that you’ve included the delete item view. Could you include that one? Also if this is a live site people will be using and it deals with money I highly suggest taking the time to create tests. This book is amazing for teaching that: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/pages/book.html#toc

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have included the views that add or delete items from the Cart. I want to be able to create an order of items that are created in a specific order and allow the user to be able to delete/edit the items from the order. I will make it a requirement to replace the items if they are deleted before the user can complete the order. I am not sure if I should have one model for the order or separate models for each step in the order. I decided to go for separate models because I thought the items would be easier to reference when editing or deleting them.

Comment: I don’t have all the details. From what I see I would have made it one order class with an additional field like `type` to designate between top and bottom. You have a lot of duplicated code which is prone to hide bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are redirecting to the `”products”` page once the items are deleted. The `urls.py` file isn’t included otherwise I could validate the redirect name `”order_summary”` is correct.

Each place you see this in the delete view

`return redirect("product", slug=slug)`

It should be this instead.

`return redirect("order_summary")`

That way it sends you to the order summary when completed.

Comment: I have the redirect going to the products page which shows the item that has been deleted. It is when I select a button to go back to the cart to see the order summary the order_summary.html does not show but defaults to a landing.html. I can see the items displayed in the order summary before anything has been deleted so I am not sure why the order_summary.html is not rendered after deletion.